# Custom CursorLoader to load items based on a selection argument overkill?

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

Good day all, Just wondering on a tiny dilemma . I have a custom CursorLoader that loads all items from an SqliteDatabase in the loadInBackground.

```
@Override
public Cursor loadInBackground() {
    final String[] TIMER_PROJECTION = new String[]{
           MyDatabaseModule.KEY_ID, MyDatabaseModule.KEY_NAME, MyDatabaseModule.KEY_GROUP, MyDatabaseModule.KEY_TASK};

    Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.getAllItems();  //method in Database
    return cursor;
}
```

if you want to get data for items with specific group name like `dbAdapter.getItems(String GroupName)` or get on the column groups like `dbAdapter.getAllGroups()`, Would creating a new Custom CursorLoader() for all this be too much or would it be better to just stick to `dbAdapter.getAllItems()` as shown in the code and manipulate the cursor from there? Thank you

Comment: custom `CursorLoader` ? what for? why dont you just create a custom `ContentProvider` instead?

Comment: @pskink am working with an sqlite database that's why.

Comment: and what prevents you to use custom `ContentProvider` ?